# Multiple fields assignment in Django models

Tags: python, django

I have several fields in my models that share the same caracteristics and I would like to declare them in one line with something like this:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    id, name, brand = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Or:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    id = name = brand = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

instead of doing this:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

But Django complains with a `TypeError` in the first case saying that `'CharField' object is not iterable`, and with `admin.E108` error in the second case.

So my question is how can I declare multiple fields that share the same caracteristics in a single line of code with Django? it looks to me that the second cases is not related to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```py
id, name, brand = [models.CharField(max_length=12) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Thanks! it will make my models.py thinner :)